# Usage of group by clause in the below criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Consider the below table

```
ID  Data Date
1   A    7/19/2011
1   A    6/12/2011
2   B    7/19/2011
2   B    8/5/2011
3   C    7/19/2011
```

Expected Output:-

```
ID  Data Date
1   A    7/19/2011
2   B    8/5/2011
3   C    7/19/2011
```

The query has to select the rows whose date value is max among the all the values.

Comment: No. When i was trying to do group by based on DATA. I was getting error. So, tought of clarifying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
  ID,
  Data,
  MAX([Date]) AS MaxDate
FROM
  TableName
GROUP BY
  ID,
  Data
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you would want to use `GROUP BY` and `MAX()`.   You would be grouping on columns ID and Data.

Answer (score -2):

try this,

```
SELECT distinct * FROM tableName GROUP BY Data ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Thanks.